# How to paste values between two dataframes when conditions are respected

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, paste

I have a large dataframe (my_DF) with 4 important columns: ID (1-->100), YEAR (2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005), MONTH (January --> December), LENGHT (continuous values from 0.1 to 1.0).
A thing like:

```
        YEAR      MONTH       ID   LENGHT 
1       2000     january      S1   0.2 
2       2000     january      S1   0.3
3       2000     january      S1   0.1 
4       2000     january      S2   0.5
5       2000     january      S2   0.3 
6       2000     february     S1   0.9
7       2000     february     S1   0.4 
8       2000     february     S1   0.6 
9       2000     february     S3   0.4
10      2000     february     S3   0.3 
11      2000     march        S1   0.7 
...
```

I need to add a new column to the dataframe, filled with the median lenght for each unique situation, so for each ID, YEAR and MONTH values.

I succeded in obtain the values I was looking for, thanks to aggregate:

```
agg <- aggregate(my_DF["LENGHT"], by = list(my_DF$YEAR, my_DF$MONTH, my_DF$ID), median)
```

In this way I obtain the values I wanted, but, of course, this just create a new dataframe.
I'm failing in finding a rapid way to paste the values of the dataframe "agg" in a new column of dataframe "my_DF", basing on the YEAR, MONTH and ID corrispondence.

For instance, I want obtain a thing like:

```
        YEAR     MONTH       ID   LENGHT   MONTHLY_LENGHT_MEDIAN
1       2000     january      S1   0.2           0.2
2       2000     january      S1   0.3           0.2
3       2000     january      S1   0.1           0.2
4       2000     january      S2   0.5           0.4
5       2000     january      S2   0.3           0.4
6       2000     february     S1   0.9           0.6
7       2000     february     S1   0.4           0.6
8       2000     february     S1   0.6           0.6
9       2000     february     S3   0.4           0.35
10      2000     february     S3   0.3           0.35
11      2000     march        S1   0.7           0.7
```

So, I'm wondering if a conditional command is suitable in my case (if, ifelse...).
Unfortunately, I'm not good with these commands... How could I do?
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of summarising with `aggregate` and then `merge`, directly use `ave` from `base R` to create a column

```
my_df$MONTHLY_LENGHT_MEDIAN <- with(my_df, ave(LENGHT, YEAR,
                  MONTH, ID, FUN = median))
mydf$MONTHLY_LENGHT_MEDIAN
#[1] 0.20 0.20 0.20 0.40 0.40 0.60 0.60 0.60 0.35 0.35
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
my_df %>%
      group_by(LENGHT, YEAR, MONTH) %>%
      mutate(MONTHLY_LENGHT_MEDIAN = median(LENGHT))
```

#### data

```
my_df <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L), MONTH = c("january", "january", 
"january", "january", "january", "february", "february", "february", 
"february", "february"), ID = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", 
"S1", "S1", "S1", "S3", "S3"), LENGHT = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 
0.3, 0.9, 0.4, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this in one line using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[ , median := median(LENGHT), by = .(YEAR,MONTH,ID)]

> dt
    YEAR    MONTH ID LENGHT mean median
 1: 2000  january S1    0.2 0.20   0.20
 2: 2000  january S1    0.3 0.20   0.20
 3: 2000  january S1    0.1 0.20   0.20
 4: 2000  january S2    0.5 0.40   0.40
 5: 2000  january S2    0.3 0.40   0.40
 6: 2000 february S1    0.9 0.60   0.60
 7: 2000 february S1    0.4 0.60   0.60
 8: 2000 february S1    0.6 0.60   0.60
 9: 2000 february S3    0.4 0.35   0.35
10: 2000 february S3    0.3 0.35   0.35
```